# Parse ABI file to get the method signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, abi

I have a simple Ethereum contract

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
    contract SampleContract {
    uint storageData;
    function set(uint x) {
        storageData = x;
    }
    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storageData;
    }
    }
```

I have complied it and here's the ABI JSON:

```
    [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "set",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "get",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

I want to parse this JSON file in such a way using node JS that it returns me the method signatures i.e. method names, their inputs/outputs with the type.

I thought to parse this JSON using JSON.parse.

While I am able to get the method names in an array using .map method , i am not able to get the input values and types as these are returned as [Object].